# Static ip tied up up with previous network adapter driver

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, network-adapter

Background: Windows 10, functioning properly for months. The ethernet network adapter has a statically assigned ip for a custom application to interface with custom hardware. Recently, the network adapter was enumerated from Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM to Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM #2.

When I try to assign the static IP to the updated network interface, it says that the Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM is still using that address, even though it does not show up in device manager (not even as a hidden device).

Unfortunately, the IP address that it needs to be set to is hard coded in the application (I didn't write the application).

What I've tried:

-Clearing dns /release /renew

-removing the network adapter from device manager, erasing driver software, then allowing Windows to reinstall it.

What I need:
For the network adapter to use a static IP that is currently used by a non existent network adapter. Either by freeing the IP from that previous adapter driver/settings or by reverting the current network adapter back to it's original state.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Does the old NIC show up as a hidden device in device manager? Or is it gone completely? Sounds like a reg key has bound the IP to a device ID.

Comment: No, it is gone completely, only showing #2. How would I go about checking that?